# How to compute mean on each column by condition

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to compute mean for each column in a dataframe.
suppose I have a dataframe like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],
                   'B':[4,4,4],
                   'C':[7,8,9],
                   'D':[3,3,3]})
print(df)
   A  B  C  D  
0  1  4  7  3  
1  2  4  8  3  
2  3  4  9  3
```

I want to get the mean as [2, 1, 8, 1]. since for column B and D only have a unique value, I hope the mean is 1, not that unique value.

How can I do that, I think I should write a function and then apply to each column by condition, but I don't know how to do that.

Hope there is anybody can help me.

Comment: You can do `df.loc[:, df.agg('nunique') > 1].mean().reindex(df.columns, fill_value=1)`... but I doubt that's the most efficient way. (so I'll let someone else point out a better way and not embarrass myself too much making it a proper answer)

Answer (score 2):

That's.. a strange thing to want.  :-) I'd advise against calling it a "mean", that will only confuse people.

Probably the simplest thing to do is to compute the real mean, and then just replace the unique columns with your override of 1.

```
In [226]: df.mean().where(df.nunique() > 1, 1)
Out[226]: 
A    2.0
B    1.0
C    8.0
D    1.0
dtype: float64
```